# Change generic font for android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fonts, android-jetpack-compose

I developed a multilingual application for android with kotlin and jetpack compose where you can see the mix of two language words in this application.

Well, I implemented different fonts to change the application language and show the whole application in the selected language.

My problem is where that I have a mix of two language sentences that text in the selected language show with the selected locale font but other language words are shown in generic fonts, not my provided language for that locale font.

So anybody has any idea what should I do in this situation to show my whole application in provided fonts?

Comment: Add your code with question .. You have to use `buildAnnotatedString` for multiple font in a single text.. That's the only way i think .

Comment: @ADM well my text isn't static cause I want to show user-provided text in my application, I think I have two choices in this case,
1 - combine my fonts with my desired English font
2 - change the generic font that when the system wants to show the glyph that is not provided in the font, selected from my submitted generic font